# discord.py - Is there a way to change a server's logo?

Tags: python, discord

I am creating a discord bot for someone that is advanced and required to have some good features, so I want to know if you could change a logo of a server simply with a command in `discord.py`

So basically, if It has a feature. Would it look like this? is it Correct?

```py
ctx.guild.change_logo("URL")
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Guild.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild.edit) method allows for changing of the icon.
Keep in mind that you need `MANAGE_GUILD` permissions to do that.

```py
# Open file in binary mode, because icon needs to be a byte-like object
with open(path_to_image, "b") as file:
    icon: bytes = file.read()
    await ctx.guild.edit(icon=icon)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the image to a variable:

```
icon = "image.jpg"
```

If the image is not in the same folder as your script try to called the variable with the full direction to the image.

```
icon = "C:\User\Name\Desktop\image.jpg"
```

Then use the function guild.change_logo with the variable icon.